# How to active this datepicker only if user focus this `#field`?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#field').datepicker();
});
```

How to active this datepicker only if user focus this `#field` ?

Comment: Your code should produce that effect, did you try it?

Comment: check the datepicker js file. is there any option for the focus.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#field').focus(); 

$(this).datepicker();
// then go for activating the datapicker
```

are you looking for this..

Answer (score 0):

try setting the `showOn` property during initialization. more documentation on that can be found here http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOn